# Django filter where multiple params match one of multiple sets

Tags: python, django

I want to query a Django model where I'm looking for instances where an entry matches one of two (or possibly more) sets.  For example:

```
class MyModel(Model):
     param1 = CharField()
     param2 = CharField()
```

I want to find instance of `MyModel` where `param1=a_param1, param2=a_param2` or `param1=b_param1, param2=b_param2`

I could do this with two queries like so

```
q1 = MyModel.objects.filter(param1=a_param1, param2=a_param2)
q2 = MyModel.objects.filter(param1=b_param1, param2=b_param2)
```

But is there a way to do this with one filter call.  I am trying to put a lot of these together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [`models.Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object:

```
from django.db.models import Q

q1 = Q(param1=a_param1, param2=a_param2)
q2 = Q(param1=b_param1, param2=b_param2)
result = MyModel.objects.filter(Q1|Q2)
```

If you have an unknown number of params set, you can build a list of Q objects and 'or' them at the end using `reduce` and `operator.or_`:

```
import operator

params = [("a1", "b1"), ("a2", "b2"), (...), ("an", "bn")]
q = [Q(param1=a, param2=b) for a, b in params]
q = reduce(operator.or_, q)
result = MyModel.objects(q)
```